# Async functions dont't work with pynput functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pynput

It's my first project and I am trying to solve one of problem with drawing rectange. When mouse isn't moving, rect dissapears so I have to do something to draw it when mouse is not moving. I am trying to solve it with asyncio library but there I cant't call
task = asyncio.create_task(draw_if_not_moving()) from not async function and if I set on_move(x, y) as async function it's not working with listener. Here is my code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import win32gui
import win32con
import asyncio
 
def draw_rectangle(left, top, right, bottom):
    hdc = win32gui.GetDC(None)
    rect = (left, top, right, bottom)
    edge_style = win32con.BDR_RAISEDOUTER | win32con.BDR_SUNKENINNER
    flags = win32con.BF_RECT
    win32gui.DrawEdge(hdc, rect, edge_style, flags)
    win32gui.InvalidateRect(None, None, True)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(None, hdc)


coordinates = []
rectpos = []
XPOS = 0
YPOS = 0
n = 0
mouse_button_pressed = False
last_pos = []


async def draw_if_not_moving():
    global rectpos
    print('aha')
    draw_rectangle(*rectpos)

def on_move(x, y):
    global XPOS
    global YPOS
    global n
    global rectpos
    global last_pos
    print('xd')
    task = asyncio.create_task(draw_if_not_moving())
    if mouse_button_pressed:
        n += 1
        if XPOS == 0 and YPOS == 0:
            XPOS = x
            YPOS = y
        else:
            rectpos = [x, y]
            while (n == 2):
                draw_rectangle(XPOS, YPOS, *rectpos)
                n = 0
                last_pos = [x, y, *rectpos]




def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mouse_button_pressed
    global XPOS
    global YPOS
    global n
    if pressed:
        mouse_button_pressed = True
    else:
        mouse_button_pressed = False
        return False


async def start_listener():
    #task = asyncio.create_task(draw_if_not_moving())
    with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()

asyncio.run(start_listene
```

Is there any chance to run it?

Comment: problem is solved, thanks for help